# How to have a video show more than the first frame repeatedly in Blender video editing

Tags: video-sequence-editor, video

I am new to Blender video editing. I have a video I took with my android phone. If I try to edit it at all (eg make a clip) it only shows the first frame for the whole duration of the video. I know how to change the start and end frame to be output and no matter what i use I get the same result. I set up the settings so the input frame rate of the video is the same as the output frame rate. I have it set for FFmpeg Video and have tried a few containers including Mpeg-4 (what the original file is) and Matrasoka. It plays the audio just fine but only uses the first frame from the video as it plays. When I drag through the sequencer it clearly show multiple different frames. Any one know what I am doing wrong?

I turned the file into an AVI and tried using that instead and it did fine. This seems odd to have to do this so I am still curious if someone knows what I was doing wrong but using the AVI to resolve the roadblock I was having.

I tried to share the blend file on blend exchange. The associated mp4 is a large file I did not upload so I am not sure if this will help. I also added a screen shot of my settings. I removed all the other stuff I had in the sequencer (animations etc) to simplify things. The issue still occurs if I use the mp4 file from my phone. When I turned it into and avi the problem went away.
[image: screen shot of blend file and settings]

Comment: maybe share your blend file, so we can check it out...?

Comment: This is most likely an issue with the codecs your phone uses. For performance reasons, to be able to record video in real time while keeping up with storage writing speed limitations, some times phone cameras use poor compression or skip on adding keyframes, making the file hard to read with Blender limited codecs.

Comment: Oh okay. Got it. Interesting. Next time I make a video I will try using my computers built in camera to see how that works.

Comment: If the phone video codec has challenging compression try using ffmpeg or handbrake to convert the file to .mp4. Blender should be able to play the converted file then.